# Proof of fourier transform expression

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-transform, residue-calculus

I want to split $ J= \int_0^{\infty} e^{ik_ax}f(x) dx$ into a real and imaginary part as follows:

$ J= \int_0^{\infty} e^{ik_ax}f(x) dx = \frac{1}{2}  \widetilde{f}(k_a) +\frac{1}{2\pi i} \mathcal{P}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\widetilde{f}(k)}{k-k_a} dk  $ , where $\mathcal{P}$ denotes the Cauchy value of the integral and $\widetilde{f}(k) $ is defined as the Fourier transform of $ f(x)$:
$\widetilde{f}(k)= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{ikx} f(x) dx  $.

Does this identity have a name and how would one proof it?

Comment: "if so" - meaning if there's not a well-known name, you don't want a proof? ;)

Comment: Edit: My mistake :)

Comment: Have you googled "Hilbert transform"? Your integral involving $\widetilde{f}$ is (up to normalization) the Hilbert transform of $\widetilde{f}$, etc.